# Best Control for date input and validation in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

Is there any other good control for date field input apart from CalanderExtender of AJAX Control Toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CalanderExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) and [MaskedEditExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx) of [AjaxControlToolKit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) worked great for me. Awesome solution for date selection and validation. It can show, select and validate client culture specific dates and it's damn easy also.

Couldn't find anything better than CalanderExtender of AjaxControlToolKit.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the few I found out mostly based on jquery plugins:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/